# April 2019 photo competition, "Road trip" (Read, rules are different.)

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

For April I would like to change the rules a bit. 
The theme will be 'road trip' as suggested by one user on the site.

**One post per person but up to 5 photos in that one post, all about the 'same' road trip.**
Composite photos are welcome as well, (instead of or as one of your 5.) But only when they do not take more space than one landscape positioned photo.

The road trip can be a real trip, by car, bike, train, foot, cart, horse, boat or whatever transport you used, or a trip you would put together if you had the money, health, time or whatever you do not have now that keeps you back from it.
If your chosen mode of transport is not in this question, please still use it in your answer, as long as you would use that kind of transport regularly within your trip, not just as a mode of transport to come to the start of your trip.

Make it a short story (one line per photo will do) in which you tell from each photo how it fitted (or would fit) into your trip.
All photos should be yours, (or your travel partner at the time/your life partner and each should be named if not yours.)

Inspiration for photos:
Car(s) you owned, rented or would use if you were able to afford it. Trains, bikes, horses, carts, carriages, boats or planes your owned or used (or would use.)
You or your travel companion(s) at any point in your travel.
Places you stopped like diners, side of the road shack which sold food, motels, campsites, hotels, castles (for sight seeing,) and so on.
Animals you met.
Food.
Your pack, shoes and other bits of your travel outfit, in or after use.

Keep it non offensive.
**All photos should have a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and when the photo was taken.**
In composite photos still all parts should be yours (or your partners) and years of photos taken should be mentioned as well as the overall subject.

There is no time limit on when the photos were taken, but remember that you (or your life partner/travel companion at the time) must have taken the photo.
If there are people recognizable in the photos, you should have their permission, as legal for the country you took the photo.
Do not post your entries before the first of April, and the competition runs till the 30th of April, 23:59* and we use UTC, just as the site. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

Usually we do not like people to change their photos, but this month I think it is permissible to add to your post and adjust each photo (or replace them) within 24 hours of posting. But do not keep fiddling about with your posts, once you are happy with it, post a bit of text saying so and keep off it from then, so people who are waiting with voting know you are done.

We should remind users that submitting any pictures on the stack exchange network allows Creative Commons use of said pictures, per [Stack Exchange terms of service.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public)

Dirty-flow has won the bragging rights, the most upvoted entry this month.
Hanky Panky has won the virtual prize, a visit to some of the London museums (conditions apply, see the comment to his entry for the details.)

Comment: How does a person with just  a "dream trip" participate? I think any pictures have to be taken by us, but we don't have any because we haven't gone! The only dream trip I see here is yours. I assume you took all those pictures, just not together in the same trip, right? I could describe the trip but, even if that's allowed, it's boring because we have no pictures! There may have been  more "dream trips" if that was clarified. I could be completely wrong, which certainly wouldn't have been the first time! Am I misinterpreting something? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have to take the photos yourself. (Or use those your hubby took.) But you can use a lot of fantasy. Car here, photo with mountains in the distance, dog to go along, birds in the sky migrating, river (photo of one you have been standing in for one you would like to visit.) Use your fantasy. And while it is a way into the month, there is still plenty of time left.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We made this roadtrip in June 2018. It included the German Alpine Road (oldest tourist route in Germany) and the Grossglockner High Alpine Road in Austria.

**The fellowship of the Road** - me, my wife and our son in front of the Grossglockner - the highest mountain in Austria.
June 10, 2018
[image: Roadtrip pic 1]

---

**The car** - our Ford Focus ST.
June 10, 2018
[image: Roadtrip pic 2]

---

**The road** - a photo of the Grossglockner High Alpine Road, taken from the Edelweissspitze. It's the highest point of the road - 2571m above the sea level.
June 10, 2018
[image: Roadtrip pic 3]

---

**Another highlight on the road** - Neuschwanstein Castle
June 11, 2018
[image: Roadtrip pic 4]

---

**Some funny stuff** - Old parking meter in Füssen, Germany
June 12, 2018
[image: Roadtrip pic 5]

Comment: You have a wife and a kid? Nice!

Comment: The trip that was most upvoted in the competition period. Yours are the bragging rights.

Answer (score 11):

**101 How to In Asia** (Thailand and Cambodia 2017)

How to transport furniture...

[image]

How to handle electricity...

[image]

How to handle your drinking water...

[image]

How to handle kids...

[image]

Comment: This is so clever! Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 9):

I spent most of the summer (and some of the autumn) of 2018 on a cycle tour of North America. I could have posted so many things in a post like this, but with a limit of 5 and a theme requirement, it was hard to choose. I could do several of these easily, but only one post is allowed, so...

So I present to you five of the strangest things I saw while cycling around America this summer.

[image: The Right Wing, Tulsa, OK]
[The Right Wing](https://www.facebook.com/The-Right-Wing-117195991632220), Tulsa, OK
June 3, 2018

I saw this restaurant on my way out of Tulsa and had to snap a picture just for the hilarious name. It turns out the place has been closed for a couple of years, which is a bit odd since they seem to have gotten pretty good reviews for their wings. It could be that Oklahoma is leaning more left these days...

[image: Boathenge, Columbia, MO]
[Boathenge](http://www.boathenge.net/), Columbia, MO
June 13, 2018

A partial reconstruction of Stonehenge, with boats and apparently some tongues in cheek. Next to the [Katy Trail](https://bikekatytrail.com/), the longest and oldest continuous rail-to-trail bike path in the USA.

[image: Kiosk, McDonald's, Kirksville, MO]
Kiosk, McDonald's, Kirksville, MO
June 19, 2018

I've never seen anything like this before or since. The sheriff's department runs public announcements, a police blotter and local wanted posters on this kiosk inside McDonald's. I'm not sure why it claimed to be showing weather from Florida. I felt weirdly unsafe with this kiosk around.

[image: Cattle guard, Vinton, IA]
Cattle guard, Vinton, IA
July 13, 2018

This cattle crossing, and one like it about a half mile away, keep cattle from a nearby pasture off the [Cedar Valley Nature Trail](http://cedarvalleynaturetrail.com/). The trail [detours](https://goo.gl/maps/fUDytDTQj4C2) around a parcel of land owned by someone who refused to sell or allow the trail to cross his field.

[image: World's largest frying pan, Brandon, IA]
World's largest frying pan, Brandon, IA
July 13, 2018

Just minutes after the above cattle crossing I ran into the [world's largest frying pan](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Worlds-Largest-Frying-Pan/153044004712074). The picture doesn't do it justice unless there are people nearby; the pan is eight feet in diameter.

Comment: Hi Michael! These are great choices! It's so cool that they came from such different parts of the country, yet all fell into the same category! Thanks for adding all the links too. These pictures definitely made me want to learn more! I live in the States, and you gave us some ideas for future travel!!

Answer (score 7):

Heli Ride over London, UK. **14 July 2018**

**1) The Ride:** Robinson R44. **Location:** Wycombe Air Park (EGTB)

[image]

**2) Outskirts**

[image]

**3) Fulham Football Club**

[image]

**4) Buckingham Palace and Hyde Park**

[image]

**5) Tower Bridge and St Katharine Docks**

[image]

**Credits**: My Wife captured all these photos, iPhone was mine.

Comment: You have won the virtual prize this month, a trip combining four visits to museums in London, choice out of the British Museum, the V&A, the Natural History Museum, National Gallery, National Portrait Gallery,  the Science Museum and the Tate Modern.  
Just the entry to the normal collection, valid as long as the entry prices are as published in April 2019, not covered are, among other things, travel, special exhibitions, food, drinks and souvenirs, donations and cloakroom costs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That prize is going to make me intellectually rich! very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The pictures in this post are from my roadtrip in the US in 2018. I started in California, and also ended up in Nevada, Arizona and southern Utah (I took a flight somewhere in between, but I think it still counts as a single road trip).

1) This is my rental car in  Yosemite value. It is one of the stops on the iconic road from Yosemite Village to Glacier Point. It think it is slight beyond the famous Tunnel View point where you definitely have to stop to enjoy the view.
[image]

2) This view is one of the last turns before reaching Glacier Point. It is amazing how after quite a drive you all of a sudden get a view over the Yosemite Valley again. Definitely worth the drive (or hike, which doesn't go all around the mountain)
[image]

3) Just a few days later I crossed the Hoover dam. Twice, actually, because the road across the dam is not the main road anymore.
[image]

4) This picture just gives an impression of the endless roads of the Grand Canyon state, Arizona. This one is extra special, because it is on the historic Route 66.
[image]

5) Some wildlife on the road. Of course I've been to the famous canyons, but a less visited site is the Valley of Fire state park close to Las Vegas. Definitely worth a visit.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have this dream, win the lottery, lock up the house and start walking. See how far you come. Santiago de Compostella, Spain, or maybe Rome, Italy, as both are traditional destinations.

[image: narrow lane between a fence and a hedge.]
Velsen Zuid, November 2012.

I would walk the small lanes to the nearest 'official starting point' for the old pilgrim routes, Haarlem.
Here a photo of the 15th century church with some 21th century entertainment next to it, photo taken out of a ferris wheel.

[image: St Bavo, Haarlem]
Haarlem, Old Church or St Bavo, Photo taken 20 April 2019

From there I would walk south again. Possibly start with a bit west, as the dunes near Haarlem are great for walking.

[image: Rough ground in the Dunes near Haarlem]
Dunes south/west from Haarlem. Photo taken November 2012.

Walking in good weather is great but it is very well possible to see great things if you walk when rain is frequent, like this puddle in the path.

[image: trees reflecting in a puddle.]
Photo taken November 2012 somewhere near Haarlem.

A couple of weeks into my tour I am likely to walk through Amiens, where the cathedral of the city was likely build with money pilgrims donated on their way to the south of France, Spain and Italy.

[image: The west elevation of the Cathedral of Amiens, France.]

Photo taken 1 April 2019, in very nice evening sun.

As you can see there is a lot more of that 'road trip' to take photos of. So this post may be continued when I have won that lottery, so I can say goodbye to the day job and spend my time walking.

Answer (score 2):

My wife (in a Guardhouse?) at the [Basilica de San Gregorio Ostiense](https://www.turismo.navarra.es/eng/organice-viaje/recurso/Patrimonio/3122/Basilica-San-Gregorio-Ostiense.htm), a huge church atop a mountain above Sorlada, Navarra, España.

[image]

Comment: What is the road trip character of this photo?

Comment: Character?  Most folks would say I'm quite a character.  We had to use a road to get there.  What exactly do you want to know about it?

Comment: The rules said one to five.  I don't expect to win, but I figure the purpose is get people to share enjoyable pictures, not to merely award an intangible prize to a single person.

Comment: @Sue, till now we have always let simple 'breaks of the rules' run if the people were not about to win. If the votes start to come in he can add the missing explanations and it will be able to win. Otherwise, I have no problems with it being here as it is.

Comment: Whatever.  I thought I read "not more than five" and one (or two if there hadn't been a problem) is definitely not more than five.  I have more pictures of every trip than I can count, and many of them are good.  And now that I am on the laptop, I could probably post more.  But I don't expect to compete with the "Right Wing" restaurant.  :-)

Comment: Chuckle.  It happens!